# Create a Datetime from Modified with Static Time

Tags: date-time

I have a need to create a Calculated Column that is a Datetime based upon [Modified]-1, but with a static time of 11:59:59 PM. Something like this:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Modified]-1), MONTH([Modified]-1), DAY([Modified]-1), HOUR(23:59:00), MINUTE(23:59:00), SECOND(23:59:00))
```

That clearly doesn't work, but I don't have any idea of the syntax to do this and there is no documentation about creating a datetime that I can find.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use two formulas (I haven't tested this):

```
=DATE(YEAR([Modified]-1), MONTH([Modified]-1), DAY([Modified]-1)) + TIMEVALUE("11:59 PM"))
```