# Set SharePoint DateTime field using Calculated Value with todays date but static time

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I am trying to create a deployment calendar that sets the default deployment start time to todays date, but always 5PM.

I have looked around and found this previous question ([Create a Datetime from Modified with Static Time](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191970/create-a-datetime-from-modified-with-static-time)), however when I change the query to suit my requirements above, it throws a syntax error.

> Sorry something went wrong.
>
> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

I have tried the following and get the same error each time:

`=DATE(YEAR([Created]), MONTH([Created]), DAY([Created])) + TIMEVALUE("05:00 PM"))`

`=DATE(YEAR([Today]), MONTH([Today]), DAY([Today])) + TIMEVALUE("05:00 PM"))`

`=DATE(YEAR(Today), MONTH(Today), DAY(Today)) + TIMEVALUE("05:00 PM"))`

One thing that does work for some reason is simply typing: `=Today`. This sets today's date and sets the time to 5PM like I want, but I'm not sure if I can trust it to work as there's nothing specifically setting the time to 5PM. I am unsure why 5PM is shown.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try using `Today()` in your formula instead of just `Today`. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ganesh Sanap, usually to get current date we use this formula:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```